# how to set pm2 node.js app on windows server?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, pm2

i have this configuration:

1. aws EC2 windows server with node.js and pm2 installed on it.
2. Route 53 domain.
3. elastic IP for the server.
4. running app on the server on port 80 using pm2.
5. my app using express web app framework.

my questions is how to connect the domain name (on route 53) with the pm2 app on the server.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create one record set pointing to EIP of your server in route53 and use.

If you have multiple servers:

1. Create one ELB
2. Attach instances to it.
3. Add CNAME entry from ELB to route53 record set.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i create a record set and point it to the EIP but not working.